# Python - Windows and Startup Scripts

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I have a python script that maps a network drive. The problem? It will not start on boot on the Windows XP machines. It's a shortcut placed in the All Users> Startup folder. The shortcut just points to a native .pyw script. Is there something special with Python and Windows as far as the startup folder is concerned? Here is what I have tried.

1. Startup Folder "All Users"
2. Starup Folder "Individual User"
3. Registry settings
4. Scheduled Tasks

Nothing has worked, all I can think of is converting it to an .exe, but that's not an option considering the script changes constantly and I would have to compile it way to many times. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That won't work because the All Users startup folder is a part of the user profile, and so nothing in it gets executed until someone actually logs on.  If you want it to run at boot consider a computer startup script in the local group policy (Start | Run | gpedit.msc)

XP won't execute Python directly (unless you have file associations set) so you'll need to call your python interpreter and pass it the full path of your script as a parameter (via a batch file or whatever your preferred approach is).

**This will only work with Windows XP Pro**

If you have XP Home you are better off asking on SuperUser instead.

Answer (score 0):

My Idea would be to make the script read a config file where you specify the changing options and convert it to an Exe afterwards.

Comment: Do I need an .exe to even run it at boot for Python? I guess that's the first question, the information is a little sparse out there.